# Numericupdown arrows turning black when form is minimized

Tags: c#, winforms, numericupdown

I am using a numericupdown in my form, but I don't need the arrows, so I hide them on the form load event, it works fine, but when I minimize the form and maximize it again they turn black

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            numericUpDownX.Controls[0].Visible = false;
            numericUpDownY.Controls[0].Visible = false;
        }
```

[image: Numericupdown with black arrows]

Comment: Several workarounds could be found by googling "numericupdown hide arrows", but maybe you don't need `NumericUpDown`, and actually need a modified `TextBox` instead.

Comment: The size of the UpDownEdit Control is recalculated in many occasions (of course, it has to be resized, re positioned, adapted to Themes settings etc.). The private [`PositionControls()`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/UpDownBase.cs,1089) method handles this. The UpDownButtons control's bounds is always subtracted from the size of the TextBox, no matter whether the control is visible. So hiding the buttons leaves their box unpainted and the TextBox doesn't cover it. You'll have to recreate the `PositionControls()` method yourself.

Comment: Or, if it's enough, clear the NumericUpDown's Graphics with the background color and make the control wide enough so the *numbers* shown in the TextBox won't reach the location where the UpDownButtons control would be located and you won't notice that *a piece* is missing.